# Rewrite в .htaccess

Tags: apache, веб-программирование, .htaccess

Хочется добиться следующего:

```
http://www.domain.ru -> https://domain.ru
https://www.domain.ru -> https://domain.ru
http://domain.ru -> https://domain.ru
```

Набросал такое:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.ru$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но почему-то на https://domain.ru дает циклический редирект.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.ru/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=domain.ru
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Чтобы улучшить ответ, можно добавить краткое объяснение, как он помогает бороться с бесконечным перенаправлением, даже если вам кажется, что приведённый фрагмент является самоочевидным.